# JSONException: No value for pageCount

Tags: android, json

In the app I am creating, I search for books from the Google Book Api. For example consider this link https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=php

I can display the json objects I want in the screen as a list view, and start a new activity with the book's detailed data when a row is clicked. Even if everything is shown in screen without any crash,I am getting the following exception.

```
08-04 09:30:07.897 29829-30069/com.example.android.booklist 
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for pageCount
```

I honestly don't know why this is happening. When I debug the line of code that gets the pageCount int, the number of pages are read without any problems. Here is my json parsing code.

```
private static List<Book> extractFeatureFromJson(String bookJson){

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(bookJson)){
        return null;
    }
    // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding earthquakes to
    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    String thumbnail=null;
    try {
        JSONObject baseJSON = new JSONObject(bookJson);

        JSONArray itemsJsonArray = baseJSON.getJSONArray("items");

        for(int i = 0;i<itemsJsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject item = itemsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject volumeInfo = item.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");

            String title = volumeInfo.getString("title");

            JSONArray authorsArray = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
            String authors = formatListOfAuthors(authorsArray);

            String language = volumeInfo.getString("language");
            String date = volumeInfo.getString("publishedDate");

            // This line gives me the described exception.
            int pageCount = volumeInfo.getInt("pageCount");

            if(volumeInfo.has("imageLinks")){

                JSONObject imageLinks = volumeInfo.getJSONObject("imageLinks");
                thumbnail = imageLinks.getString("smallThumbnail");
            }

            Book b = new Book(title,authors,thumbnail,date,language,pageCount);

            books.add(b);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return books;
}
```

Any ideas?

For the actual json response,you can check the link at the beginning of the question.

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: Seems that `pageCount` is an optional property (in you link with 10 results, only 9 have pageCount). Before trying to parse it, you should check if it exists

Comment: @MatPag, I see 10 `pageCount` items in the linked JSON. Probably it changes according to some conditions.

Comment: @MatPag, themes you are right. For another query I get 9 of 10 have pageCount. This one for example https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=c++

Comment: @VladMatvienko I'm italian and i'm getting italians books. So i think it uses some custom informations to retrieve the list and should be different for users of different countries (there are `country` and `language` properties inside the results)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that `pageCount` is an optional property (in your link with 10 results, only 9 have pageCount).

Before trying to parse it you should check if the property exists.

You have 2 choices:

1- Use a default value when trying to retrieve the value

```
//this will give you 0 as default if pageCount not exists
int pageCount = volumeInfo.optInt("pageCount");
```

2- Check if the property exists before retrieving it

```
//this will set pageCount value only if pageCount exists
if (volumeInfo.has("pageCount")){
    int pageCount = volumeInfo.getInt("pageCount");
}
```

Book API is lacking a bit of documentation. If you search [here](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/reference/volumes) the property `volumeInfo.pageCount` hasn't notes about is optionality